# Recommendations for Javascript Editor on Windows?

Tags: javascript, editor

Are there any good recommendations anyone can provide for a good Javascript editor on Windows?

I currently use combinations of FireBug and TextPad but would hate to miss out on the party if there are better options out there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case you're a .Net programmer: VS 2008 has pretty great JS support including [intellisense](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/06/21/vs-2008-javascript-intellisense.aspx) on dynamically added methods/properties and comfortable [debugging](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/19/vs-2008-javascript-debugging.aspx).

Comment: To anyone still searching - these are not the droids you're looking for.  VS 2008 may be *OK*, but is far from great.  Even VS2010 is pretty useless in this regard, as far as intellisense is concerned.  It also inaccurately flags get and set property declarations as bad syntax.  Supposedly MS is working on all of this, but in the meantime we wait and look elsewhwere.... :(

Comment: for a better support look at resharper http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/whatsnew/index.html#JavaScript

Comment: I'm not sure about .NET support but there is also [atom](http://www.atom.io). Made by the people at Github in NodeJS.

Answer (score 11):

I know [jsight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26897/recommendations-for-javascript-editor-on-windows#26905) already mentioned this, but [**Aptana Studio**](http://aptana.com/) really is a great, free editor for JavaScript if you find yourself doing a lot of work with it - it has great support for most of the well-known libraries. If it were not for the fact that I work with C# in addition to JavaScript, I would use Aptana for all of my work.

Answer (score 10):

I use NotePad++ and am happy (of course, that is when I am not using Visual Studio).

NotePad++ contains support for intellisense type feature as well.

Answer (score 8):

*(This is a cross-answer post)*

### Netbeans

I've tried out all of the above and my vote goes for Netbeans, which has been mentioned. However the answer didn't really sell you on the features which [you can find here](http://wiki.netbeans.org/JavaScript).

It has:

- Intellisense including jQuery built in
- Extended (Eclipse-style) documentation for functions
- Function and field outlining
- Code folding
- Refactoring

It makes Visual Studio 2010's Javascript support look very primitive.

[image: Netbeans]

Comment: thanks for the screenshot! I will try it, do I have to install JDK to use it? Also, the HTML5 and PHP version would be best for javascript, correct? Thanks again!

Answer (score 6):

The [Zeus](http://www.zeusedit.com) editor has support for Java Script.

It has the stock standard set of features like code folding and syntax highlighting features etc, but more importantly Zeus is fully scriptable and Zeus scripts can be written in Java Script.

Comment: +1 I like the way it works with JSLint.

Answer (score 4):

The best that I've ever used is Netbeans, although its kind of heavyweight for some tasks due to being a fullblown multi-language IDE (not just Javascript).  I've also had pretty good experiences with Aptana IDE, though, and I hear that IntelliJ is good if you don't mind paying the price.

Answer (score 4):

**[WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/)**. If you have used any Jetbrains products you'll love it. It has Autocomplete and all the other javascript goodies.  Even node.js support is provided. Check it out

Answer (score 2):

If you are using eclipse, then I would recomend [JSEclipse](http://www.interaktonline.com/products/eclipse/jseclipse/overview/)

Answer (score 2):

I'm still a huge fan of HomeSite, even though Adobe discontinued development in May 2009: http://www.adobe.com/products/homesite/.

Answer (score 2):

Both NetBeans and Eclipse have JavaScript editing support. The latest version of NetBeans actually does a really good job. They are both free and you can use them for other languages as well, this way you have a chance to get to know the IDE and the shortcuts as well.

Answer (score 2):

Komodo Ide or Komodo Edit of course.

Answer (score 1):

[Editra](http://editra.org/index.php) may be worth a look, the code colouring isn't bad, and I believe it has plugins to enable script execution.. Although I have **not** used this myself.

Answer (score 1):

[GVim](http://www.vim.org/) is still awesome - not only for JavaScript for for almost all languages.